# datatables how to scroll to specific row without pagination

Tags: datatables

I have a datatable of about 90 rows long. The user performs some operation and the table must scroll to the corresponding row.

I know about the scroller plugin, but the user has demanded to have no pagination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the code below to scroll page to particular row if you're not using scrolling:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   paging: false
});

var $row = $(table.row(30).node());   
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $row.offset().top }, 2000);
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/ouoawta2/) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, where 'table' is datatable, and target row has 'shown' class:

```
var $row = $(".shown");
table.context[0].nScrollBody.scrollTo(0,($row[0].offsetTop));
```